# Is there any way to inspect indexeddb user permission?

Tags: indexeddb, service-worker

Usually caught error: `UnknownError: The user denied permission to access the database.` So, is there any way to inspect indexeddb user permission?

Comment: what browser, what code

Comment: @Josh I use indexedDB in service worker. When using indexedDB open api, caught above error. The error mostly occurred in Chrome Mobile, and a few other browsers. And at the same time, it works in a lot of situations.